# Manually publish pdb to symbol server

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, debug-symbols, pdb-files

I have a 3rd party library, fortunately I have the pdb's for the 3rd party library. I have a symbol server in my organization, I have a local symbol cache folder on my desktop.

This 3rd party library in question is used across a lot of projects, I would like to publish this to my organization's symbol server so that developers can get the best debug experience when they are debugging code in and around this library.

I have found alot of reference around how to configure symbol server using TFS build, how to configure Symbol server path in Visual Studio, but this not what I am after. I would like to know how I can publish the pdb's for this 3rd party library to the symbol server.

Any ideas / hints will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have found your answer to this already, but the solution is "SymStore", part of the Debugging Toolkit for Windows (and possibly in the platform SDK these days).

You can find more at [Using SymStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

SymStore allows you to register the PDB's (and exe/dll files too if you want) with a symbol server, either by copying the files in or by embedding links to the files.